# How to use Jedis Client 3.x with Spring-boot 1.5.x?

Tags: spring-boot, stream, jedis

I want to use Stream function in Jedis which only available in Jedis 3.x ,but I can not change the Spring boot version to 2.2 for some reasons and now the Springboot version is only 1.5.x:

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.11.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
```

If I use Jedis 3.x with SpringBoot1.5.x,

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

it will report errors:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: redis.clients.util.SafeEncoder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    ... 50 common frames omitted
```

which is caused by the Jedis version( if changes the version of Jedis to 2.9.x,this error will disappear, but the Stream function can not be used). It is a dilemma.

Does anybody has any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Can not use  Jedis 3.x with SpringBoot1.5.x, must upgrade the SpringBoot to 2.x.